# Python3 datetime negative number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to time a the run time of a function using datatime.now() and subtracting their differences to get a floating point number of seconds.

```
tStart = datetime.now()

*function*

tEnd = datetime.now()

# microseconds for more precision then convert to seconds
time = tEnd.microsecond - tStart.microsecond
print(listLength, "\t", '{0:.6f}'.format(time/1000000))
```

Example Error:

```
3250    0.043427
3500    -0.940100
3750    0.075566
```

Am I wrong for assuming that I can convert back to normal seconds with a standard conversion? Is there a better way of doing this? I tried using seconds but it only gets to hundredths of a second precision so I don't get the 6 decimal digits I need.

Comment: If tEnd=11:11:11.000000 and tStart=11:11:10.940100, your code shows -0.940100. This is because you ingore date,hour,minute and second of time. Try to modify "time = tEnd.microsecond - tStart.microsecond" to "time = tEnd - tStart", modified code will show correct answer.

Comment: @Fumu7 That is what I had previously, but when I go to print time I always get 0.000000 because I had been printing time.second but it seems to work when I use microseconds and convert it back to seconds. Thanks for helping me find where I went wrong.

Comment: Corrected code: "time = tEnd - tStart", "tMicrosec= time.sconds*1000000 + time.microseconds","print ('{0:.6f}'.format(float(tMicrosec)/1000000)".

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to calculate the offset in seconds between two dates, the *time* module may be more what you are looking for. It expresses dates in seconds since the UNIX epoch, so subtracting two dates gives natively a result in seconds :

```
import time
tStart = time.time()
*some code*
print time.time() - tStart
```

Comment: The problem with the time module is it does not precisely measure in fractions of seconds.